# Cannot see the created database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I created a database from the mysql prompt. It is named "spring_security_tutorial".

Then, I created a user named "erdinc@localhost" and granted the user all the privileges for the "spring_security_tutorial" db.

Here is the "show databases" result when I am connected as root:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------------+
| Database                 |
+--------------------------+
| information_schema       |
| mysql                    |
| performance_schema       |
| spring_security_tutorial |
| springsecurity           |
| test                     |
+--------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the result of the command "use spring_security_tutorial" when I am connected as root:

```
mysql> use spring_security_tutorial;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'spring_security_tutorial'
```

Here is the result of the command "select user(), current_user()":

```
mysql> select user(), current_user()
+----------------+----------------+
| user()         | current_user() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here are the privileges of the root and erdinc users:

```
mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'erdinc'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for erdinc@localhost                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'erdinc'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*8DCDD69CE7D121DE8013062AEAEB2A148910D50E' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `spring_security_tutorial`.* TO 'erdinc'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I cannot use the spring_security_tutorial database as root user even if I can see it with "show databases".

Also, when I am connected as "erdinc@localhost", I cannot even show the mentioned database.
It just shows the test and information_schema databases.

I am looking up for this for a couple of hours now. Actually I used to use mysql in the past, either something changed in the usage or I am missing something very obvious because this used to be a trivial task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may have missed it, but I don't see you calling `CREATE DATABASE spring_security_tutorial DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` anywhere above nor `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` to make it valid.

Comment: Run the following query to check if the database was created properly

    SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA

Comment: @Prix I created the database with the command: "create databse spring_security_tutorial". I did understand the "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" part. What will it make it valid?

Comment: @Namphibian I ran the recommended query and it displays the spring_security_tutorial database as other databases. What should I expect for an unproper creation?

Comment: Thank you for the answers by the way, I gave up on that database and created another one. This one works as expected. The former one still cannot be used. I don't know how I managed to corrupt it. If this question is inappropriate, please inform me so that I can delete the whole question.

Comment: @user2428786 What happens when you run: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON spring_security_tutorial.* to 'erdinc'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '*8DCDD69CE7D121DE8013062AEAEB2A148910D50E';` ? If possible post what was affected.

Comment: @Prix When I did that with the root user, I did not get an error but after that I could not connect with the user "erdinc" with my normal (non-encrypted) password. I ran the same command with my normal password, again I did not get any errors and I also could connect with the normal password. But still, the "spring_security_tutorial" database is not seen.